# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Wire' to data type int. (Microsoft SQL Server Report Builder)

Tags: sql-server

I am troubleshooting a report that just stopped working out of nowhere. Here is the error and below is the query code. I have no idea where the word 'Wire' is coming from.

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Wire' to data type int.

This won't allow me to post the code saying it's too long so I don't know how to show you the code.

Comment: You most likely have the column `Wire` being compared implicitly to an int but you have a value in `Wire` that is **not** an int.  You need to find the comparison and troubleshoot.  Most likely you just need to explicitly convert whatever you are comparing with `Wire` to `varchar`.

Comment: @avery_larry I checked and there is no 'Wire' column anywhere. How can I post the code so you can see that?

Comment: 'Wire' is not a column, its a datavalue in a varchar column which you are attempting to convert to an int.

Answer (score 0):

Run SQL Server Profiler and check out the queries that are being sent to the database. Enable the events for Exceptions (under Errors), RPC Completed, and SQL Batch Completed. For RPC Completed, make sure that the TextData column is selected.

That'll be enough for you to catch the error when it happens and you'll see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for all the help. I modified the query for the dataset so that checkno = ‘0’ instead of checkno = 0. This is a varchar field and needs the ticks. There was a change to the checkno column in the database from INT to VARCHAR in so checkno = 0 has to have the ticks around the zero.I have no idea why it stopped working as there were no updates to this server or application. Issue resolved!